# Adding a list "default new form" inside a web part page

Tags: 2010, list, list-form

I have created a custom list. On the ribon under List Tools > List > Form Web Parts there is "Default New Form". Is there a way that I can embed the content of this form in a web part page?

**Edit**
I do not have infopath 2010 at the moment. I will try and get this. If anyon knows of a way todo it without that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Sharepoint Designer to do that.
With Sharepoint Desinger you can create a new "new form" for your list and set it as default.
[Sharepoint Designer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16573)
[Creating a custom form Sharepoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-form-using-sharepoint-designer-HA010378258.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you customize the list form with InfoPath, you can then use the InfoPath form web part to embed the form on a web part page.